# Scaling Axis in iOS Charts (MPAndroidChart for iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm pretty sure this is a bug but thought I'd ask on here in case someone else had experienced something similar and had any advice.

I'm using iOS Charts to show a chart in my App. As standard the y axis goes from 0 to whatever it needs to. Obviously it isn't always a good idea to have th chart start as 0 as you will often end up with the actual data all being towards the top of the chart... So I want to scale the axis nicely.

Problem is when I use

```
chartHolder.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true
```

I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on line 93 of ChartDataSet.Swift (The line is if _yVals.count == 0)

And if I try to set min and max values for the axis like so

```
chartHolder.leftAxis.axisMinimum = minY1
chartHolder.leftAxis.axisMaximum = maxY1

chartHolder.rightAxis.axisMinimum = minY2
chartHolder.rightAxis.axisMaximum = maxY2
```

The axis don't go to the top of the chart as in this pic

[image]
So how do I get my axis looking and fitting nicely?

Comment: Crashes for me as well when I set it to true, but on line 1374 in BarLineChartViewBase.swift.

Answer (score 0):

I met crash while setting `autoScaleMinMaxEnabled` to true. Seems really like a bug

If you are not familiar how it works, you should avoid use it for now.

But for what you needs, I feel you can combine `customAxisMax` and `customAxisMin`,

and set `yAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false`, so your yAxis will no longer start from 0, it will start with the minimum value you set or calculated.